# CsvError: Invalid Opening Quote: a quote is found inside a field at line 9618

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise, node-csv-parse

I have this error when I try to parse kepler_data.csv using csv-parse using promises following Adam and Andre Negoi NodeJS course.
Here is the code:

```
function loadPlanetsData() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.createReadStream(
            path.join(__dirname, "..", "..", "data", "kepler_data.csv")
        )
            .pipe(
                parse({
                    comment: "#",
                    columns: true,
                })
            )
            .on("data", (data) => {
                if (isHabitalePlanet(data)) {
                    habitablePlanets.push(data);
                }
            })
            .on("error", (err) => {
                console.log(err);
                reject(err);
            })
            .on("end", () => {
                console.log(
                    `${habitablePlanets.length} habitable planets found!`
                );
                console.log("Done reading!!");
                resolve();
            });
    });
}
```

I tried to indicate `relax-quotes` but it doesn't work. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
parse({
  comment: "#",
  columns: true,
  relax_quotes: true,
  escape: "\\",
  quote: "'",
  delimiter: ",",
  ltrim: true,
  rtrim: true,
  record_delimiter: "\n",
  skip_empty_lines: true,
  relax_column_count: true
})
```

Comment: Thanks. This has helped alot.
However this is what works for me:
`
parse({
                    comment: "#",
                    columns: true,
                    relax_quotes: true,
                    escape: '", quote: ',
                    delimiter: ",",
                    record_delimiter: "\n",
                    skip_empty_lines: true,
                    relax_column_count: true,
                })
`

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.